# Using different maths font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, mathspec

I am using Fedora 13 and it had TeX Live 2007 by default. I installed `texlive` and then I wanted to use the [`mathspec`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/mathspec.html) package which TeX Live 2007 version doesn't seem to have. Can anyone tell me as to how to install the `mathspec` package in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there packages for newer versions of TeX Live for Fedora 13? If so you could upgrade to them (I don't know where to look for Fedora updates).

If you can't find suitable upgrades for your system, you can download the package from CTAN. Place the [mathspec.sty file from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/) into `~/texmf/tex/latex/mathspec`.

If that also does not work (maybe `mathspec` needs a newer version of XeTeX than the one shipped with TL2007), you can manually install a new version of [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

Comment: Go to http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive for information about Fedora and TeXLive.